# destroy disconnected parts from main part

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sandbox, 2d-games

I'm working on some kind of 2D sandbox game  in "Unity". In this game, you can create your battle figure like "robocraft" .

Details;
You can create your battleship on the another interface. if click "play", works "save" and "dontdestroyonload". Main Part is fixed. Other parts are child and in same tag with main part if they are unified eachother and main part. I used for this "collision stay".

And i want to create physics like in this picture;

[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhMMk.jpg

long story short; If below or above green part stay still, grey parts stay still because of connection but destroy both of them, all grey part must destroy.

I'm trying to use "flood fill algorithm" but I didn't know how to integrate to my codes.

Do you know any other solutions or can you give any example about "flood fill" for kind of this problems?

Already thanks for the people who trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

My take on flood filled algorithm for your case would look like this:

Determine neighbours for each part. It will be maximum of 4 parts, or 8 if adjacency by corners also counts.
Create a list of neighbours and you can use OnCollisionStay to populate each list with neighbours.

When battleship is hit, this is where algorithm starts.

Create a `Queue<Part>` (or whatever collection suits you)

1. For each destroyed part

1.1) For each destroyed part's neighbours

1.1.1) Push its neighbours to the queue

1.1.2) Take the the first element from the queue. Mark it with flag as checked, and push it to the new checkedQueue.

1.1.3) Check if the part in question is a base part. If it is, it means there's a connection from neighbour of the destroyed part to the base, and those parts don't need to be destroyed. Exit the loop.

1.1.4) If it's not, push it's neighbours to the initial queue.

Continue with checking all parts. If you run out parts in the queue without exiting, it means there's no connection to the main part, and all parts on checking queue should be destroyed.

Obviously don't check or push parts that already have checked or destroyed flags. Be careful not to analyze all damaged part's neighbours at once, or you will end up with all parts connected to the core :) Also you might need to clear queues at appropriate times as well as reset flags when needed.

Hope you can read through that pseudo code, formatting on mobile is a challenging task. It probably isn't the most optimised code in the world, but it can serve as a good start.